# How to create a program that crashes with a segfault, but without core dump

Tags: c, crash, segmentation-fault, coredump

I am currently writing in C a UNIX-like shell, and in order to test my shell, I need to create a program that creates a segmentation fault, but without `Core Dumped` being print.

I already wrote a program that does a segfault (something like `int *a = 0; *a = 3;`), and when I run it the terminal print `Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)`.

What code should I write, or what command should I use, in order for my terminal to only print `Segmentation Fault` when I run it, and not `Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)` ?

Edit:
I don't only want the output to be shortened, I also want to create a program that does not create a core dump when it crashes (such that when I use the `WCOREDUMP` macro on the exit status of the program, given by `waitpid`, it returns 1.)

Solution:
I made a program that only raise the `SIGUSR1` signal ; By running it, I get a 'crash' but without `(core dumped)` being print - which is what I am looking for.

Code, in case someone needs it:

```
#include <signal.h>

int main()
{
    raise(SIGUSR1);
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output:
`User defined signal 1`

Comment: @ScottHunter I also need to prevent the core dump from being created, such that when I call the `WCOREDUMP` macro on the exit status, it returns 1

Comment: After the `fork` but before the `execvp`, have your shell do `setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE,...)` with values that set the core dump size to zero. In a real shell, look at the `limit` and/or `ulimit` command(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mess with `signal.h`

`

```
#include <signal.h>    

void sig_func(int sig)
{
    exit(1);
}

int main (void)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, sig_func); // sets a new signal function for SIGSEGV
    raise(SIGSEGV); // causes the signal function to be called

    return 0;
}
```

`

in this example, it should exit with 1, printing nothing, change the `sig_func` to whatever you need.

By the way... With signal you're completely overwriting what happens when that signal is raised. If you got rid of the exit call the program would keep running, with whatever undefined behavior that constitutes.

Comment: In this example, the program doesn't crash - if i want it to crash, I have to remove the `signal` call ; but even by raising the `SIGSEGV` signal, my terminal (zsh) still prints `Segmentation Fault (core dumped)`. But, you reminded me of the raise function, so I made a program that raise the `SIGUSR1` signal; by running it, it effectively 'crashes' without creating a core dump.

Comment: it crashes per the function call, check the return code.